# Can we have a place for "definitive" questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, sffaq

There are a number of questions and topics that are now regularly closed as dupes of some generally accepted definitive question. As an example, new licensing question get closed pretty quickly as dupes of [this one](https://serverfault.com/q/215405/9278).

I know we can simply bookmark those questions, set them as favourites, or whatever other method we prefer for the purposes of close voting. However, I believe there would be value in having a place set aside for such questions to which new members can be pointed via the FAQ (at least those very few who ever bother to read the FAQ).

Is this viable? Do you even see value in the idea?

**Edit**

Both answers so far have completely missed the point of the question. I am *not* looking for a way to group answers, search by tag or any other such thing. I am asking of we can have a designated place for those questions which are routinely used as the ultimate or definitive question. i.e. Questions such as the one I linked. I would also like the FAQ to have a reference to that area so that people can read those questions, rather than post yet another one to be closed as a dupe.

Comment: John - if nothing better comes along then perhaps we can have a community wiki here on meta to keep track of them all if that is agreeable to enough people? Not what you're asking for, I know, but it might 'get the job done' in the meantime and if we find ourselves referring to it enough then that might support having something fancier put in place?

Comment: @Robert, while that wouldn't be the ideal solution (which I suspect will ever happen) it would certainly be useable. Perhaps someone who already has a list of those questions can kick it off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorting all questions or just those with a specific tag is some help, but I'd also like to see what John's asking for - a list of questions that we've decided are Canonical - an excellent answer to a recurring question, one that we'd refer to when closing very similar questions.

Comment: Exactly. I have to admit I'm very tempted to create a Canonical meta-tag just to keep these together; for the time being I keep them in my favorites, but that doesn't help anyone else.

Comment: having a tag for them on the main site is a good idea and quite do-able I would say.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like: this: https://serverfault.com/tags/licensing/faq

you can get here for any of the tags on the site, but going to `/tags/<tag>/faq` or clicking the 'faq' tab when you are looking at a tag's page.

This tab is sorted by incoming links to that question.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally see

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/

and the faq link on any tag mouseover

[image]